# sh: 1: node: not found (npm ERR! yorkie@1.0.3 install)

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu

I have a small bash script that downloads and extracts node.js and then tries to run npm install (yes I have read about nvm but would like to understand this issue)

**build.sh**

```
NODE_VERSION='v10.0.0'
NODE_FOLDER="node-${NODE_VERSION}-linux-x64"
NODE_ARCHIVE="${NODE_FOLDER}.tar.gz"
NODE_DOWNLOAD_URL="https://nodejs.org/dist/${NODE_VERSION}/${NODE_ARCHIVE}"
wget "${NODE_DOWNLOAD_URL}"
tar -xf ${NODE_ARCHIVE}  

export NODE_PATH="${NODE_FOLDER}/bin"
export PATH=$NODE_PATH:$PATH
node --version
npm --version
npm install
```

When I run the above script I get part of the dependencies installed but at some point it fails with:

```
v10.0.0
5.6.0

> yorkie@1.0.3 install /home/user/repos/webapp/webapp-frontend-vue-cli/node_modules/yorkie
> node bin/install.js

sh: 1: node: not found
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! yorkie@1.0.3 install: `node bin/install.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the yorkie@1.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2019-12-17T15_48_53_166Z-debug.log
```

And the **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "webapp-frontend-vue-cli",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-beta.15",
    "browser-sync": "^2.24.4",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Any suggestion to what is wrong - both npm and node are found in the current shell that is running the script.

Comment: Are you sure it's "node" and not "nodejs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of your exported `NODE_PATH` is not absolute. Change the line to

```
export NODE_PATH="${PWD}/${NODE_FOLDER}/bin"
```

and don't forget to add a shebang as the first line of your script

```
#!/bin/bash
```